# One thousand random selections of a Tree's node

Tags: c, algorithm, tree, probability

I need to write a code where I add the node into a tree, then I randomly pick an element of a binary search tree randomly. All the elements should have about equal probability of being selected. I use the following nodes as an example for my tree.

```
               60
               / \
             41   72
            /  \
           23  57
          /  \
         1   32`
```

from those nodes I count them with my function `countT(nodeT *p)`, Then I had implemented the following algorithm/pseudocode

```
function random()
   //returns a random element n = countT
function probability_random_of(int x, int y)
 // get the probability of gettin gvalue x on the nth call of random
  for(i=0;i<1000;i++)
      random()
  probability_of_(x)
```

My question and/or problem is to know if I have a correct approach or I am overthinking it. If i am incorrect please feel free to guide me in the correct solution.Also, I have the idea of using either binomial distribution or normal distribution.

The output of the code will be,

```
Probabilities after 1000 random selections are
p(60) = 0.135000
p(41) = 0.135000
p(72) = 0.152000
p(23) = 0.147000
p(57) = 0.156000
p(1) = 0.147000
p(32) = 0.128000
```

this output bugs me because it negates the statement I said before

> all element should have about equal probability of being selected

which means all of the element should had the exact result.

Comment: The container is not relevant to determining how often something is "selected" (i.e. picked by the random number generator)..  Really, what you're testing is the random number generator itself :)

Comment: You haven't presented any actual code, and even your pseudocode is hard to follow.  With that said, if you are selecting randomly then you cannot expect to see the frequencies of all the elements being identical, but I might expect them to be a little closer than you observe.  Running larger trials (i.e. with, say, 10000 or 100000 selections) might help clarify whether you're a seeing random variation or true non-uniformity.

Comment: Did a quick test where I generated 1000 random numbers between 0 and 6, using a decent random number generator, and the results I got were 150,131,164,129,123,141,162. So what you're seeing is nothing unusual.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the tree, that's not really relevant.  This code should tell you how often the random number spits out a given number between (e.g.) 0 and 1000 (just an arbitrary maximum number of values I picked):

```
#define MAX_VALUES  1000

int index;
float percentages[MAX_VALUES];
int counts[MAX_VALUES];
int maxiterations = 1000000;
for( index = 0; index < MAX_VALUES; ++index )
{
    counts[index] = 0;
}

// Initialize the generator...
srand((unsigned) time(&t));

// Now test for some number of iterations.
for( index = 0; index < maxiterations; ++index )
{
   int value = rand() % 1000;
   ++counts[value];
}

// At this point, each value of the "count" array should be roughly
// equivalent.  But there's no guarantee that they'll be exactly
// equal.  This will calculate the percentages.
for( index = 0; index < MAX_VALUES; ++index )
{
    percentages[index] = (float)counts[index];
    percentages[index] /= (float)maxiterations;
}
```

Again, there's no guarantee that the `percentages` will be exactly the same.  But they oughta be close, within a particularly small deviation.  The higher the value of `maxiterations`, the closer and closer the percentages should (theoretically) be.

Comment: Can you explain me what is t?`time_t t i` is a correct way do declared?. Also how should I initiate the call int random(int x, int y)?

Comment: That just seeds the random number with the current time.  You have to seed it with something :)